# Make hyperlink in code listing

Tags: hyperref, listings, verbatim

I'm trying to achieve something I thought would be basic functionality. Just a hyperlink where it appears (in a code listing). It would be better if it was possible to follow the link for a reader. But it returns an error message and is a source of painful confusion.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, breaklines,escapechar=|]
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2

$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{MyFunction}|(x);

$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}|(x);

$ tar -xvjf tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
$ ./configure --cc=gcc
$ make
$ make install
\end{lstlisting}
```

How it looks (without the hyperlink).

[image]

The error message seems to have little or nothing to do with what I try to do.

```
Missing $ inserted.

 
‪./sections/3-method.tex, 110‬
You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’.

Use $...$ for inline math mode, and \[...\]or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode.

This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x}).

Learn more
<inserted text> 
                $
l.110 ...0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}
                                                  |(x);
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.110 ...0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}
                                                  |(x);
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
 Expand
```

The typography is broken. It seems to be because TeX tries to be smart and force me into math mode which has nothing to do with what I'm doing. The "solution" I used was from [Inline links in code listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314903/inline-links-in-code-listings)

[image]

The following attempts also failed miserably with broken typography.

```
$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive}|

$ wget |\url{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}|;
```

Minimal not working example follows. It is easy to see that nothing works. The rendering is broken in all attempts to create such a simple feature as a hyperlink.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, breaklines,escapechar=|]
$ wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2
$ wget |\href{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc\_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}|
$ wget |\href{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc\_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}{\nolinkurl{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc\_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}}|
$ wget |\url{https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/tcc/0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a-1/tcc_0.9.27+git20200814.62c30a4a.orig.tar.bz2}|
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: Just escape `_` properly. [symbols - Escape character in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex)

Comment: ps. TeX is not smart, it does exactly what you tell it to do. If you tell it to do the wrong thing it errors out.

Comment: @user202729 But the formatting disappears if I try to escape the _.

Comment: Write a minimal working example first.

Comment: @user202729 I included a more exact example. If I make the text a hyperlink, the font becomes wrong. Now I wish I stayed with Microsoft.

Comment: You always have the option to switch back...? Although we don't have many Microsoft-lovers here so supports would be on their support forum

Comment: That's not a minimal example though. For LaTeX you need a documentclass line.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because of the underscore in the text. Underscores are only allowed in math mode and so TeX switches to it. Either escape the underscore as `\_`, or use `\nolinkurl` or `\url` (the last naturally produce a different link).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, breaklines,escapechar=|]
$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{https://...tcc\_0.9.27}|(x);

$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{\nolinkurl{https://...tcc_0.9.27}}|(x);

$ wget |\url{https://...tcc_0.9.27}|(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it does not render with the same font as the rest of the commands :-(

Comment: You didn't provide a complete example so I can't know which font you are actually using and which one you want. But you can adapt the fonts, see the docu of url.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted [the second answer in the linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315696/250119) a bit. This should leave the font correct.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\gdef\bt@HR@url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
\newcommand\btSetUrl[1]{\gdef\bt@HR@url{#1}}
\newenvironment{btHyperref}
{\begingroup\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}
{\end{lrbox}\bt@HR@box{\@tempboxa}\endgroup}

\newcommand\btHR{%
  \begin{btHyperref}\bgroup\aftergroup\bt@HR@endenv%
}
\def\bt@HR@endenv{%
  \end{btHyperref}%   
  \egroup
}
\newcommand{\bt@HR@box}[1]{%
  \href{\bt@HR@url}{\usebox{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash, breaklines, escapechar=|, moredelim={**[is][\btHR]{@}{@}}]
$ wget |\btSetUrl{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}|@https://...tcc_0.9.27@(x); # with the link
$ wget https://...tcc_0.9.27(x); # without the link
$ wget |\href{http://foo.com/MyFunctionDocs.html}{https://...tcc\_0.9.27}|(x); # Ulrike's answer, wrong spacing
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: (MWE taken from Ulrike's answer with modifications.)